# Click on openlayers map and open a node form

Tags: entities, javascript, location

I have an [Opelayers](https://www.drupal.org/project/openlayers) map in a Drupal installation. I need to do 3 things:

> **1)** I would like to add a behaviour on the map so when someone is
>   clicking on it the add node  form to appear and the geodata to be
>   populated from the coordinates of the clicked point. So far I use draw
>   event from behaviour but I cant trigger the form to open (in a
>   colobox)
>
> **2)** I would like also the same to happen when I click on a link in
>   pop-up (I have implemented a link there "add a node here")
>
> **3)** Is it possible to have a link of the views of the current location
>   to the pop-up? Something like "see all nodes of current location");

Thanks in advance

I post a similar question here [Dynamically change widget type in node edit form](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77557/dynamically-change-widget-type-in-node-edit-form)

Comment: Which Drupal version you're using? I understand that you're using Openlayers module for 7.x?

Comment: exactly.I also checked this module https://www.drupal.org/project/getlocations but I am not sure whether it covers my needs..